# How can I append an Image using a jquery function with 1 param?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, document

How can I append an Image using a jquery function with 1 param?

```
function imageadd(param1){
    $('#random').append(...)
}
```

with the src being `src="gallery/param1.jpg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `img` element and assign the `src` attribute. Aassuming `param1` was the `src` you could do it like this:

```
function imageadd(param1){
    $('#random').append($('<img />').attr('src','gallery/' + param1 + '.jpg'));
}
```

or, if `param1` is the full url already:

```
function imageadd(param1){
    $('#random').append($('<img />').attr('src', param1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function imageadd(param1)
{
    $('#random').append("<img src='gallery/" + param1 + ".jpg'");
}
```